# Android: Unable to insert data in mysql database using php

Tags: php, android, mysql

Am making a sample app where the user can add id and name . But the i don't get any errors nor i get the output.

Here's the source code for java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String name;
    String id;
    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;
    int code;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText e_id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText e_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                id = e_id.getText().toString();
                name = e_name.getText().toString();

                insert();
            }
        });
    }

    public void insert()
    {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101/API/insert.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

            if(code==1)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
    }




}
```

and the insert.php

```
<?php
        $host='localhost';
        $uname='root';
        $pwd='john123';
        $db="mydatabase";

        $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
        mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];

        $flag['code']=0;

        //if($r=mysql_query("insert into sample values('$id','$name') ",$con))
        if($r=mysql_query("insert into sample (id,name) values('$id','$name') ",$con))
        {
                $flag['code']=1;
                echo"hi";
        }

        print(json_encode($flag));
        mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and the error is :

```
0000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=9150448, downTime=9150174, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
01-30 07:48:47.762      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 1﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-30 07:48:47.871      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 2﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-30 07:48:47.871      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 3﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 07:52:36.521      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 1﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-30 07:52:36.571      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 2﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-30 07:52:36.571      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 3﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 07:52:38.921      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 1﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-30 07:52:38.941      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 2﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-30 07:52:38.941      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 3﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 07:52:41.761      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 1﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-30 07:52:41.781      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 2﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-30 07:52:41.781      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 3﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 07:52:42.771      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 1﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-30 07:52:42.822      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 2﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-30 07:52:42.822      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 3﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 08:01:32.341      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 1﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-30 08:01:32.391      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 2﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-30 08:01:32.391      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 3﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 08:01:35.532      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 1﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-30 08:01:35.581      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 2﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-30 08:01:35.581      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 3﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 08:02:23.291      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 1﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-30 08:02:23.421      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 2﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-30 08:02:23.421      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 3﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 08:02:27.131      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 1﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-30 08:02:27.251      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 2﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-30 08:02:27.251      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 3﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 08:06:30.621      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 1﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-30 08:06:30.841      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 2﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-30 08:06:30.841      982-982/com.example.john.mysql_insert E/Fail 3﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling network stuff (`insert()` method) on main thread, which is not allowed in Android development. Try using `AsyncTask` to wrap `insert()` logic. Besides, consider if you already added `INTERNET` permission to your manifest file.